# Linear Mixed-Effects Models for a big spatial auto-correlated dataset

Tags: r, linear-regression

So, I am working with a big dataset (55965 points). I am trying to run a LME accounting for correlation. But R will return me this

> Error: 'sumLenSq := sum(table(groups)^2)' = 3.13208e+09 is too large.
>    Too large or no groups in your correlation structure?

I can not subset it since I need all the points. My questions are:
Is there some setting I can change in the function?
If not, is there any other package with similar function that would run such a big dataset?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
require(nlme)
my.data<- matrix(data = 0, nrow = 55965, ncol = 3)
my.data<- as.data.frame(my.data)
dummy <- rep(1, 55965)
my.data$dummy<- dummy
my.data$V1<- seq(780, 56744)
my.data$V2<- seq(1:55965)
my.data$X<- seq(49.708, 56013.708)
my.data$Y<-seq(-12.74094, -55977.7409)

null.model <- lme(fixed = V1~ V2, data = my.data, random = ~ 1 | dummy, method = "ML")

spatial_model <- update(null.model, correlation = corGaus(1, form = ~ X + Y), method = "ML")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have assigned a grouping factor with only one level, there are no groups in the data, which is what the error message reports. If you just want to account for spatial autocorrelation, with no other random effects, use [gls](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/gls.html) from the same package.

Edit: A further note on 2 different approaches to modelling spatial autocorrelation: The corrGauss (and other corrSpatial type functions) implement spatial correlation models for regression residuals, which is different from, say, a spatial random effect added to the model based on county/district/grid identity.